# Import a complete image folder with Vite

Tags: javascript, import, vite

I'm starting to work with vite.js and I use a plugin to "optimize" the size images. But for this I have to import the images I use in the project one by one...

Is there any way to import a whole folder (all the images simultaneously) in vite.js??

Thanks

I thought that doing import "assets/*" could work .
But I don't know the way for doing this...

Comment: What is the plugin and what version of it are you using? Please [edit].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what plugin you're referring to, however, I hope this tip points you in the right direction as the question is titled *"Import a complete image folder with vite"*.

This is how I would import/export all images from an `/assets` folder:

Say you have a setup with images like:

```
.
├── src
├──└── assets
├────└── image1.png
├────└── image2.png
└── [...]
```

Add an `index.js` within the `/assets` folder:

```js
import image1 from './image1.png';
import image2 from './image2.png';

export { image1, image2 };
```

Then, within your project, you can use the images like so (example in the `App.jsx` file):

```js
import { image1, image2 } from '../assets';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    <img src={image1} />
    <img src={image2} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App
```

Again, I'm not 100% sure about your issue exactly because I'm not sure what plugin you're referring to and/or what exactly you're trying to do. Nonetheless, hope this helps in some way. If not, please provide more info, code snippets, and any possible additional information that could aid someone in pointing you in the right direction. :)